Creating a list (column) of Excel workbook's tabs
I use Excel for Microsoft 365 Ver. 2402 Build 16.0.... 32-bit.
I have a workbook with multiple tabs.
Is there a simple way to generate a list (column) of tab names? Do I have to create a script?
I will need to do that about once a week with a different workbook each time.

You can use this following formula in Excel, however this needs to save the file as either .xlsm or .xlsb because it uses Excel Macro 4.0 formulas
=TEXTAFTER(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"- ")


The above formula needs to define in Name Manager as SheetNames and place the formula in refers to :, next in cell enter the following formula to get the desired output
=TOCOL(SheetNames,3)


Another option is to use the 'Automate' tab of the ribbon with this Script written in Office Scripts:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const sheetNames: string[][] = workbook.getWorksheets().map(sheet => [sheet.getName()]);

    workbook
        .getActiveWorksheet()
        .getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, sheetNames.length, 1) // Adjust for your output range
        .setValues(sheetNames)
}

The example shown will write the sheet names to the range starting in cell A1 of the active sheet.
The call to .getRangeByIndexes is zero-indexed and the example shows 'start at row zero, column zero and create a range of sheetNames.length rows and 1 columns'.
So, for example to write it starting from B2, you would do this instead:
.getRangeByIndexes(1, 1, sheetNames.length, 1)

For some reason, @Mayukh Bhattacharya's answer won't work for me so here's an alternate (same idea though):
Create a New Named Range:

Then in, say cell A1 do the formula:
=Index(sheetNames,row(a1))

And drag down. If you want to hide the workbook name, you can work around that with additional formulas.
